# Implement AWS Cost allocation tags via Account factory for terraform(AFT) or Landing zone accelerator(LZA)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-control-tower, aws-landing-zone

I manage AWS account with AWS Control Tower, Account Factory for terraform and Landing zone accelerator. my question is are there any way to implement cost allocation tags with AFT or LZA? I didn't find any document or resources in AWS documentation

I checked aws documentation, but didn't find any documents or resources in AWS documentation

Answer (score 0):

You would need to import your AWS account responsible for the billing (Control Tower account) into AFT, for that you just need to import it as any other account which already exists before AFT is deployed.

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/import-existing-aws-control-tower-accounts-to-account-factory-for-terraform/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/aft-update-account.html

Then you will have a customisation pipeline for you Control Tower account. There you can add the terraform code to create the cost allocation tags https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ce_cost_allocation_tag

After importing the CT account you can also start to manage SCPs, SSO, Police tags, etc as code.